# LARAVEL: could not find driver (SQL: select * from `app_settings`) (View: /var/www/mendar-dev/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php)

Tags: mysql, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I get the following error(s) when trying to access an application I have downloaded online (I am the first to run into this issue, I have checked.):

> could not find driver (SQL: select * from `app_settings`) (View: /var/www/mendar-dev/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php)

My .env file looks good, and is well configured.

Running LEMP stack on ubuntu 18.04 TLS.

EDIT: I'm also seeing this error on the Laravel installer: could not find driver (SQL: select * from `app_settings`)

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you made sure that the SQL connection is configured properly?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes I did. I tested the mysql database and it connects fine.

Comment: **How** did you test that? From a running PHP script?

Comment: what php version you use?

Comment: I am running Laravel 5.8.38 with PHP 7.3.17 and nginx 1.15.8... Though I believe the app is written in an older version of Laravel... I bought it online. Will that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini. Is PDO enabled? If not remove the *;* from *;extension=pdo_mysql.so* and restart php-fpm.

Comment: Yup, it stil does not work... Were you able to access the link? I believe you'll get more insighst...

Answer (score 0):

I've had pdo_mysql missing. You need both; PDO and pdo_mysql.